# Thank you for fix/fixing the pending items.

Tags: present-participles

Which form should I use after thank you? Which one is correct? Is there third option?

> Thank you for **fix** the pending items.
>   Thank you for **fixing** the pending items

Comment: Simple rule of thumb I learned from school. *Preposition+noun phrase/gerund*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can say:

Thank you for {something}.

Thank you for {doing something}.

> Thanks for *that quick fix*. <sup>something (**fix** is a noun here)</sup>
>
> Thanks for *fixing that problem* so quickly. <sup>doing
>   something</sup>

The bare infinitive does not qualify either as {something} or as {doing something}.

> Thank you for **sing**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>  Thanks for **singing**. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> Thank you for **fix**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup> Thank you for **fixing** it. <sup>grammatical</sup>